# CArchive serialization with operators << >> no operator found which takes a left-hand of type cArchive

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, mfc, carchive

Following this tutorial, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3bfsbt0t.aspx I implement this code:

```
class Esame: public CObject
{

public:

INT voto;
INT crediti;
BOOL lode;
CString nome;
Esame(){}
Esame(CString nome, INT voto, BOOL lode, INT crediti) :nome(nome), voto(voto), lode    (lode), crediti(crediti) {}

void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

protected:
DECLARE_SERIAL(Esame)
};

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(Esame, CObject, 1)

void Esame::Serialize(CArchive& ar){
CObject::Serialize(ar);
if (ar.IsStoring())
{       
    ar << voto << lode << crediti;
}
else
{       
    ar >> voto >> lode >> crediti;
}
}
```

then I call:

```
CFile file(_T("file.and"), CFile::modeCreate);
CArchive afr(&file, CArchive::store);
Esame e;
afr << e;
```

but i get
     << operator no operator found which takes a left-hand of type cArchive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't provide an overload of `operator<<` for your class `Esame`. The article you linked to doesn't do this either, so perhaps you intended to do this instead:

```
CFile file(_T("file.and"), CFile::modeCreate);
CArchive afr(&file, CArchive::store);
Esame e;
e.Serialize(ar);
```

So, you call the `Serialize` function directly, and the implementation in your class uses `operator<<` to serialize the required primitive member variables and calls `Serialize` on other complex objects.

As the tutorial shows:

```
void CCompoundObject::Serialize( CArchive& ar )
{
   CObject::Serialize( ar );    // Always call base class Serialize.
   m_myob.Serialize( ar );    // Call Serialize on embedded member.
   m_pOther->Serialize( ar );    // Call Serialize on objects of known exact type. 

   // Serialize dynamic members and other raw data 
   if ( ar.IsStoring() )
   {
      ar << m_pObDyn;
      // Store other members
   }
   else
   {
      ar >> m_pObDyn; // Polymorphic reconstruction of persistent object  
      //load other members
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, but so I lose the "comfort" of using CArchive: I can simply overload << and >> for a whatever ancestor class; the help of CArchive would be (I believe) to automatically doing the overload of << >> operators( that I think is done by DECLARE_SERIAL and IMPLEMENT_SERIAL macros). Overloading << >> manually is the usually system

Answer (score 0):

```
afr << &e;
```

pointer type needed.